# Cannot open any applications on windows server 2008 R2 Standard edition

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a server running on Windows server 2008 R2. It is recently added as a member of a domain. I am not able to start any applications in thew server. When I tried to open Event viewer it errored out saying "The page file is to small to complete the action".

I am experiencing same problem when I tried to open Sql server Management studio, task scheduler or any other application. The windows server serves as a production database server, but our applications are not experiencing any problems. Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you get Task Manager to start? Sounds a whole lot like it's out of RAM.

Comment: what size hard drive are you using and how much free space is left?

Comment: It has 32 GB of ram. And only 5 GB is being used by all applications. Also The system has plenty of Hard drive space.

Comment: "Plenty" doesn't tell me anything.  Do you have any idea how big your current paging file is?

Comment: Thanks Greg, I have not changed the default settings on my server for page file size. I cannot connect to my server either remotely or directly. When I connected directly my profile did not load, It was a blank blue screen and could not open anything.

Answer (score 1):

What i would try:

- Put the server in a temporary OU in Active Directory, and bock GPO inheritance. Then replicate accross DC + gpupdate on this server. If it works again, it comes from GPO
- You may use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), from Microsoft, to understand what it fails to do.
- Did you try to first launch a Cmd prompt with elevated rights (right click, run as admin..) and then launch eventvwr ?

If you get the CMD but eventvwr fail, can you try this:

wevtutil qe Application /c:3 /rd:true /f:text

wevtutil qe System /c:3 /rd:true /f:text

Comment: Thanks Mathieu, Our domain is very simple network with 4 servers. I am a starter in AD DS. Our domain does not have any OU's and I haven't created any group policy. I am not able to remote connect to the server using Administrator account, also I tried connecting directly to the server and my profile does not load any thing. It is just a blank blue screen. How ever I could launch task manager(CTL+SHIFT+ESC) and found everything normal.

Comment: do did you resolve it ? from task manager, you can do file then run and then cmd to get a command prompt. Or type explorer to launch explorer and maybe get the desktop loaded.

Comment: Thanks, I did not resolve the problem. I will try to launch the event viewer from Task manager.

Comment: I could not start cmd.exe. It errored out "The application was uable to start correctly(0xc0000142)"

Comment: In the taskmanger under performance tab, in system It shows the Commit (GB) 127/127. Is it a problem?

Comment: you said it had 32GB of ram, but you see 127GB of comitted memory in task manager ? If it's real, it's a big issue. Start by rebooting and then immediately get the desktop