# Windows server 2008 R2 error :The page file is to small to complete the action

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a windows server 2008 R2 standard edition. The system suddenly stopped accepting remote desktop connections. When I tried to connect directly to the console, I am unable to start any applications. I got errors "The page file is to small to complete the action". Under takmanager in performance the system shows "Commit(GB) 127/127". What does this imply?

The system has 32 GB ram, 5 raid disks each 150 Gb

Comment: Is this a dupe of your other question? http://serverfault.com/questions/222703/cannot-open-any-applications-on-windows-server-2008-r2-standard-edition

Comment: What did you find to be the problem after you completed your reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rebooted the server. I found that the problem is being caused by fdhost.exe service (Full text search). Maximum memory limit was not set on my sql server so it claims all the available RAM and fdhost.exe service then starts paging. After reboot within 20 minutes the page file grew to 127 GB again. I have configured the maximum page file size to 48 GB recommend by MS(1.5 times of RAM), then configured the maximum memory setting on SQL server.

I have also installed this hotfix for Windows Server 2008 R2 http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;981314

This fixed the problem. This is the article that says about full text search and its paging problems http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142560.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't imply anything - it's telling you that the page file is too small for the current usage of the system. How is the pagefile configured? And what are you running? FYI - A tool like Process Explorer from Sysinternals is even better than Task Manager for stuff like this.

OK - if you can't do anything from the console, and can't run any management tools remotely from another machine, reboot your server and then post what the pagefile settings are.

Comment: I haven't changed the page file settings. I would be the default value. I cannot open any other applications on the server. Only taskmanager is working.

Comment: Provide the information I have asked, please. Go to the settings, read them, and post it. No one on this site is psychic.

Comment: It could also be that the C: drive is out of space. I'd look for that.

Comment: @mfinni - I believe the op is stating they CAN'T get that info because they can't run any apps besides task manager

Comment: @Randolph - that's not impossible - but he'd be getting plenty of other errors and problems if it were the case.

Comment: @mfinni - Maybe he is, but as he's only logged in remotely with Task Manager, he's unable to tell.

Comment: @Mark - well, at this point, kishore should reboot the server and then remediate any configuration problems.

Comment: @Randolph - there's always remote management from another machine, mapped drives, etc. If none of those are working, it's time to reboot the box and fix it when it comes back up.

Comment: Agreed. I would have rebooted it by now :-)

Comment: I am sorry. I cannot open any application on the server. My user profile does not load anything. It is just a blank screen and taskmanager is the only thing I can open. I cannot even get to system properties to see the settings. I am not sure where to look for page file settings.

Comment: @kishore - go to the server and hit the power button. Power saving should recognise that as a shutdown command, and the box should shut down. Then you can restart it and see what went wrong from the Event Viewer.

Comment: Thanks @mfinni and @Randolph. The server is a production database server. The database is working and it is serving all the applications now. I would restart the server, but I am afraid to do it becuase if the services do not start up after restart I would loose a production database server.

Comment: Anyway I don't see any other alternative and I will restart in non peak Hours.

Comment: This presents a whole host of questions and suggestions. Firstly, try a remote shutdown - pshutdown or shutdown /i \\servername . Second, Randolph's suggestion should cause a graceful shutdown. Third, please don't tell me that you're not taking backups.

Comment: possibly a corrupt page file?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** In task manager insert all the memory counters in the process tab. Also look in the resource monitor(opened from the performance tab). Also use [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653). There is something eating your page file. Maybe some process is using page file to store information ( like process monitor does). Close processes that are not needed.

**Before update:** Some process is probably leaking memory badly. In the process tab of task manager add the "memory- commit size" and check which process is the offender.

Comment: Only sql server process has 3.3 GB of commit size. Others are below 100mb. But the server has a RAM of 32 GB out of which only 20% is being used.

Comment: @kishore - do you still see the Commit(GB) 127/127 in the taskmanager?

Comment: Yes. It is still showing 127/127

Comment: @lgal Serban, I tried to open resource monitor, but it errored out. I cant open any application other than taskmanager.